# Yii2 Delete Query Using Relations

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have defined a relation in Yii2 in which every website can have multiple feeds:

```
public function getFeeds() {
    return $this->hasMany(Feed::className(), ['website_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Now consider following query:

```
$ids = [2, 3];
$feeds = Website::find()->where(['user_id' => 1])->with(['feeds' => function($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->where(['id' => $ids);
}])->all();
```

The corresponding raw SQL queries are:

```
SELECT * FROM `website` WHERE `user_id`= 1 // returns 4, 5, 6
SELECT * FROM `feed` WHERE (`id` IN (2, 3)) AND (`website_id` IN (4, 5, 6))
```

My questions is, can I have delete version of this query using Active Record? Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `website` WHERE `user_id`= 1
DELETE FROM `feed` WHERE (`id` IN (2, 3)) AND (`website_id` IN (4, 5, 6))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may do as this:

```
$query = Website::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['user_id' => 1]);

Feed::deleteAll([
    'id' => [2, 3],
    'website_id' => $query
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case could be better a CreateCommand

for do this you should bild  raw query using join  eg:

```
select * 
from `feed` 
join `website` on `website`.id = `feed`.`website_id`
WHERE website`.`user_id`= 1
AND  `feed`.id  IN (2, 3)
```

or for delete

```
delete 
from `feed` 
join `website` on `website`.id = `feed`.`website_id`
WHERE website`.`user_id`= 1
AND  `feed`.id  IN (2, 3)
```

then for Yii2

```
$sql = "delete 
        from `feed` 
        join `website` on `website`.id = `feed`.`website_id`
        WHERE website`.`user_id`= 1
        AND  `feed`.id  IN (2, 3);"

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to create this query using Active Record, just like the select version.